# Is this kufr? Am I a kafir?

Tags: kufr

I said or it came into my heart that Islam doesn't make sense but I didn't act toward it. Is this a kufr act? And while I was watching a TV show its was a Hindu show there it was about cleanliness the boy said that soon our city would world's most cleaned city but after awhile there came a monster who made it unclean so I said if Allah's doesn't will something it doesn't happen but it's a Hindu show so I said it not about Rabb so did I do a sin? Did I do kufr? How should I repent!??

Answer (score 0):

If you did not act upon what you thought there is no sin on you. Ask Allah to guide you and seek information on Islam from authentic sources so that your doubts can be addressed. Be patient as the answer may not come right away.

Comment: I didn't want to think but I came into my heart and also I repented. But I kept feeling that I did kufr and am kafir so I just asked about it.

Comment: Watch out for the whispering of that shaytaan who tries to insert doubt into your heart. Even if you did as you said, ask Allah to forgive you and seek protection in Allah from these whisperings of the shaytaan,

Comment: Actually I don't even properly remember if I said or it came into my heart but I repented and didn't act toward it or believed what I said or that what came into my my heart

Answer (score -1):

Such thoughts are not taken on you.
The biggest problem in our islamic world is that we prohibit such questions. It is totally legal to ask, but you have to direct your question to specialist. Specially when it is related to faith and Allah acts.

Be more specific, what exactly motivated you to think that Islam does not make sense?

You have to distinguish between two things, willing and satisfaction.

As you said, if Allah does not will something, then it will not happen. So WILL is about good and bad. When people choose kufr, this is totally by Allah will. Allah give them the ability to choose kufr. However, this not to satisfy Allah. Quran said that.

> قال تعالى: "إِن تَكْفُرُوا فَإِنَّ اللَّهَ غَنِيٌّ عَنكُمْ وَلَا يَرْضَى لِعِبَادِهِ الْكُفْرَ وَإِن تَشْكُرُوا يَرْضَهُ لَكُمْ وَلَا تَزِرُ وَازِرَةٌ وِزْرَ أُخْرَى ثُمَّ إِلَى رَبِّكُم مَّرْجِعُكُمْ فَيُنَبِّئُكُم بِمَا كُنتُمْ تَعْمَلُونَ إِنَّهُ عَلِيمٌ بِذَاتِ الصُّدُورِ" [الزمر : 7]
>   ترجمة للهلالي-خان الآية 7 من سورة الزمر:
>   "If you disbelieve, then verily, Allah is not in need of you, He likes not disbelief for His slaves. And if you are grateful (by being believers), He is pleased therewith for you. No bearer of burdens shall bear the burden of another. Then to your Lord is your return, so He will inform you what you used to do. Verily, He is the All-Knower of that which is in (men's) breasts." (39:7) [Translation by al-Hilali/Khan]

To repent, you should seek forgiveness by estighfar

Answer (score -1):

Ibn Taymiyyah wrote: “Seeking forgiveness is from the greatest of the good deeds; and its door is extensive. So whoever senses a deficiency in his statement or his action or his circumstance or his sustenance or in the fluctuation of the heart; then upon him is Tawheed and seeking forgiveness. For in the both of them is a cure if they occur by way of truthfulness and sincerity.” (Majmu’ Fataawa 11/698)